# Как завершить выполнение программы на Python для всех процессов?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

У меня одновременно запущено 4 процесса (1 основной). Когда я хочу завершить работу, я зажимаю Ctrl + C, вызывая KeyboardInterrupt, и при обработке этой ошибки мне нужно завершить все процессы (использую модуль multiprocessing). Как это сделать?

Comment: Приведите свой код в минимально рабочем виде (без лишней логики и данных), а вообще правильное закрытие — закрыть все процессы либо присоединить к основному и закрыть основной.

Answer (score 0):

`Process.terminate()` завершает процесс